# Removing row to different tab according to specific criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a code which i was using to move row when the work Done in column 22 i want the start row to be 4 also the target sheet will start also from row 4 which am not able to achive

```js
function onEdit(e) { 
  var excl=['WMS WIP','WORK DONE','Dashboard','INBOUND ETA','SHIPMENT PRIORITY'];
  var sh=e.range.getSheet(); 
  if(excl.indexOf(sh.getName())==-1 && e.range.rowStart>3) {
    var dt=new Date();
    if(e.range.columnStart==2)sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(dt); 
    
  }
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "WMS WIP" && r.getColumn() == 22 && r.getValue() == "DONE") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WORK DONE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 4, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you add in a sample spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The logic is very simple:

`if` the current last row of the target sheet is smaller than `4`, then paste the data to row `4`. Otherwise, paste the data one row after the last row with content. I used   a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to achieve this comparison.

- I also cleared your code to avoid unnecessary calls that you repeat multiple times. For example `e.range` appears `4` times and also `var r = e.source.getActiveRange()` is unnecessary since this info again is fetched from `e.range`.

### Solution:

This will ensure that the data will pasted starting from the `4th` row of the target sheet:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  const excl=['WMS WIP','WORK DONE','Dashboard','INBOUND ETA','SHIPMENT PRIORITY'];
  const ss = e.source;
  const ar = e.range;
  const row = ar.getRow();
  const col = ar.getColumn();
  const sh=ar.getSheet(); 
  const shName = sh.getName();
  if(!excl.includes(shName) && row>3) {
    const dt=new Date();
    if(col==2)sh.getRange(row,1).setValue(dt); 
  }
  if(shName == "WMS WIP" && col == 22 && ar.getValue() == "DONE") {
    const numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WORK DONE");
    const target = targetSheet.getLastRow()>3 ? 
                   targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1):
                   targetSheet.getRange(4, 1);
    sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sh.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sh=e.range.getSheet(); 
  var excl=['WMS WIP','WORK DONE','Dashboard','INBOUND ETA','SHIPMENT PRIORITY'];
  if(excl.indexOf(sh.getName())==-1 && e.range.rowStart>3) {
    var dt=new Date();
    if(e.range.columnStart==2)sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(dt); 
    
  }    
  if(sh.getName() == "WMS WIP" && e.range.columnStart == 22 && e.value == "DONE" && e.range.rowStart>3) {
    var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("WORK DONE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } 
}
```